# How to have a container fit it's child flutter

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-layout, containers

I'm trying to replicate a feature I like in twitter.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

[image: example 3]

As you can see from the images above Twitter images are always the exact same width but the height are in respect to the image. I have been able to semi replicate this idea using BoxFit.contain but the Container doesn't fit the image.

What I have implemented]

[image: What I have implemented]

```dart
Container(
  width: 290.0,
  // height: 400,
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: 350,
    minHeight: 150,
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27.5),
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage(image[itemIndex]),
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
    boxShadow: const [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Color(0x80000000),
        offset: Offset(0, 2.5),
        blurRadius: 5,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I tried a FittedBox with no luck. I attempted a FractionallySizedBox but kept on getting an error!
If anybody could lead me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: try `fit: BoxFit.cover,`

Comment: instead of changing the resolution of the image... make container dynamic... size according to the image with min & max width, height....
or just use fit: ```BoxFit.cover;``` in `image` object

Comment: @Nikhil I think this is a step in the right direction with making the container dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the config that worked for me. It's a combo of the 2.

```
ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(27.5),
                                    child: Container(
                                      //width: 290.0,
                                      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                        maxHeight: 350,
                                        minHeight: 150,
                                      ),
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.red,

                                        /*image: DecorationImage(
                                          
                                          image: AssetImage(image[itemIndex]),
                                          
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        ),*/
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: Color(0x80000000),
                                            offset: Offset(0, 2.5),
                                            blurRadius: 5,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        image[itemIndex],
                                        width: 290,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try fixed width on Container. But most important is using `fit: BoxFit.cover,`

```dart
 Container(
  width: 290.0,
  // height: 400,
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: 350,
    minHeight: 150,
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27.5),
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage(image[itemIndex]),
      fit: BoxFit.cover, //
    ),
    boxShadow: const [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Color(0x80000000),
        offset: Offset(0, 2.5),
        blurRadius: 5,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: BoxFit.cover doesn’t give me the effect I want. I want the Red container to shrink to fit the image.

Comment: Can you remove constrains

Comment: when I remove the constraints the image won't appear b/c there is no height. I want the height to by dynamic and I thought BoxConstraints was the right way to go!

Comment: I thin I will use `Image.asset("", width:imageWidth,fit:Boxfit.cover)`

Answer (score 1):

**Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position.**

Instead of using the image as a Container background image, use it as the Container's `child` property.

```
Container(
  width: 290,
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: 350,
    minHeight: 150,
  ),
  child: Card(
    semanticContainer: true,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    shape:
        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
    child: Image.asset(
      image[itemIndex],
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Reference:** [Flutter - Understanding Constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

**Code Snippet:** See result **[here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c3c3c27c801b62ef4b31988c9dce7ab7)**.